# Generating HTML report in gulp using lighthouse

Tags: google-chrome, gulp, lighthouse

I am using gulp for a project and I added lighthouse to the gulp tasks like this:

```
gulp.task("lighthouse", function(){
    return launchChromeAndRunLighthouse('http://localhost:3800', flags, perfConfig).then(results => {
      console.log(results);
    });
});
```

And this is my *launchChromeAndRunLighthouse()* function

```
function launchChromeAndRunLighthouse(url, flags = {}, config = null) {
  return chromeLauncher.launch().then(chrome => {
    flags.port = chrome.port;
    return lighthouse(url, flags, config).then(results =>
      chrome.kill().then(() => results));
  });
}
```

It gives me the json output in command line. I can post my json [here](https://googlechrome.github.io/lighthouse/viewer/) and get the report.

Is there any way I can generate the HTML report using **gulp** ?

You are welcome to **start a bounty** if you think this question will be helpful for future readers.

Answer (score 3):

The answer from @EMC is fine, but it requires multiple steps to generate the HTML from that point. However, you can use it like this (written in TypeScript, should be very similar in JavaScript):

```
const { write } = await import(root('./node_modules/lighthouse/lighthouse-cli/printer'));
```

Then call it:

```
await write(results, 'html', 'report.html');
```

**UPDATE**

There have been some changes to the `lighthouse` repo. I now enable programmatic HTML reports as follows:

```
const { write } = await import(root('./node_modules/lighthouse/lighthouse-cli/printer'));
const reportGenerator = await import(root('./node_modules/lighthouse/lighthouse-core/report/report-generator'));

// ...lighthouse setup

const raw = await lighthouse(url, flags, config);
await write(reportGenerator.generateReportHtml(raw.lhr), 'html', root('report.html'));
```

I know it's *hacky*, but it solves the problem :).

Comment: Worked for me with JavaScript!

`const { write } = require('lighthouse/lighthouse-cli/printer');`

then

`write(results, 'html', 'report.html')`

Comment: Perfect :) Good to hear

Comment: I got it working after a couple of changes. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this issue too. I found somewhere in the github issues that you can't use the html option programmatically, but Lighthouse does expose the report generator, so you can write simple file write and open functions around it to get the same effect.

```
const ReportGenerator = require('../node_modules/lighthouse/lighthouse-core/report/v2/report-generator.js');
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more, about using this module to generate a report.

Answer (score 1):

I do

```
let opts = {
    chromeFlags: ['--show-paint-rects'],
    output: 'html'
}; ...

const lighthouseResults = await lighthouse(urlToTest, opts, config = null);
```

and later

```
JSON.stringify(lighthouseResults.lhr)
```

to get the json

and

```
lighthouseResults.report.toString('UTF-8'),
```

to get the html

Answer (score 0):

You can define the preconfig in the gulp as

```
const preconfig = {logLevel: 'info', output: 'html', onlyCategories: ['performance','accessibility','best-practices','seo'],port: (new URL(browser.wsEndpoint())).port};
```

The output option can be used as the html or json or csv. This preconfig is nothing but the configuration for the lighthouse based on how we want it to run and give us the solution.